# How to make a Rails Migration be utf-8 instead of my default latin1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, migration, latin1

I just checked my MySQL tables and I have default set as latin1. Is that generally the default?

How can I make it explicit for all my tables that I want the database to be utf-8?

I know there is a db configuration that can change the default, but I think there is also a way to do it per-migration.  How could I permanently set my rails migrations from now on to be utf-8?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`create_table(:table_name, :options => 'ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8')`

Comment: Alternatively, you can set `default-storage-engine = InnoDB` in your my.cnf for MySQL. You can also set MySQL's default character set and collation to utf8. There are a lot of options here, so you'll want to dive into the docs for more info on that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html